# VS2010 - Stepping into the .NET source

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Has anyone been able to get this going with VS 2010 SP1?

I've tried the instructions at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/serversetup.aspx

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arik/archive/2010/07/12/step-into-net-framework-4-0-source-code.aspx

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/troubleshooting.aspx

This is very frustrating.

UPDATE (More information):

My debug test code looks like this:

```
private void TestSymbolDebugging()
{
     string myValue = this.txtData.Text;
}
```

and the breakpoint is set on the only line of code in the method.

If I just F11 (step into) it skips over the line with no error but it doesn't break into anything either.

If I right click and select 'Step into specific' I have the choice of System.Windows.Forms.get_Text. This gets me the No Source Available window.

I have 'Enable .NET Framework source stepping' checked.

I have 'Step over properties and operators (Managed only)' unchecked.

I have 'Enable source server support

I have 'Require source files to exactly match the original version' checked.

In the modules window I show the System.Windows.Forms assembly is loaded.

Comment: Yes. I've gotten it working.    (do you have a specific question in mind?  A specific error?  Please thoroughly explain how far you've gotten and what isn't working.)

Comment: I've updated the question and provided more information.